# .before() and .after()

Tags: java

I have been trying to write a program which has to look whether a certain time from a csv file is after or before some values. 
However, I get the following error:

```
javaFiles\testing.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
                                        boolean before = result.format(formatter).before(calc);
                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   method before(LocalTime)
  location: class String
javaFiles\testing.java:117: error: cannot find symbol
                                        boolean after = result.format(formatter).after(calc2);
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   method after(LocalTime)
  location: class String
```

This is the code that gives the problem:

```
LocalTime calc = LocalTime.parse("06:00", formatter);
LocalTime calc2 = LocalTime.parse("17:30", formatter);

//before and after , if true its night
boolean before = result.format(formatter).before(calc);
boolean after = result.format(formatter).after(calc2);
```

For the full code please see https://pastebin.com/5EGurJig so I dont have to spam it here

Comment: We *format* object to text, we *parse* text to object. Since you used `format` you got as result text as String, but String class doesn't have `before` or `after` methods. What exactly is `result` here? If it is `LocalTime` you could try use its `isBefore` or `isAfter` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which class the variable `result` has but you are calling `before` and `after` on String, since the result of the `format` call is a string. So if `result` is a `LocalDate` as well, you can just use:

```
boolean before = result.isBefore(calc);
boolean after = result.isAfter(calc2);
```

Comment: Then it should work with the code snippet I provided in the answer

Comment: nope also gives a symbol not found.. same error basically

Comment: could you please check if theres an impor tmissing (see my pastebin), im pretty sure i imported them all ..

Comment: Did you change the method names to 'isAfter' resp. 'isBefore'? Just checked it myself and it works. Then you have a different error. Which one are you getting?

Comment: javaFiles\testing.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
                                        boolean before = result.format(formatter).isBefore(calc);
                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   method isBefore(LocalTime)
  location: class String
javaFiles\testing.java:117: error: cannot find symbol
                                        boolean after = result.format(formatter).isAfter(calc2);
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   method isAfter(LocalTime)
  location: class Str

Comment: You have to remove the `format()` call. You don't want to format your `LocalTime`, you want to call the method on the `LocalTime` directly.

Comment: haha fun to see this back 1 year and 3 months later. I was so stupid :D